# Apply VBA Macro To Filtered Cells Only

Tags: vba, excel

Got a bit of a problem. Auditors have requested an entire Excel-dump of our whole ledger, which is massive (why? Why do they want this?). I.T. have eventually managed to export it for me over several workbooks, but it appears that some lines are duplicated. There appears to be no pattern as to which ones. I've got some code to delete wholly duplicated lines, but each spreadsheets are so massive I wouldn't be able to run it on the whole dataset.

I've identified the subledgers that are affected, and though I could filter and then apply the code just to these ones. It will still take ages, but not quite as ages as going through and searching for them all 'by eye' would.

Is there a way, please, of applying the code just to the cells I have filtered? I've tried SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), but I think I was adding it in the wrong place as my macro is still searching through the whole workbook.

Original code before I added SpecialCells is as follows:

```
Dim ColN As Long
Dim MyS As Worksheet: Set MyS = ActiveSheet
Dim MyR As Range: Set MyR = MyS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
Dim NumCol As Long: NumCol = MyR.Columns.Count
Dim MyArray As Variant: ReDim MyArray(0 To NumCol - 1)


For ColN = 1 To NumCol
    MyArray(ColN - 1) = ColN
Next
MyR.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(MyArray), Header:=xlYes
Dim rowcount As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Boolean
rowcount = MyR.Rows.Count
For i = rowcount To 1 Step -1
    k = 0
    For j = 1 To NumCol
        If MyR.Value2(i, j) <> "" Then
            k = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If k = 0 Then
        MyR.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Many thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I would import the data into PowerPivot instead of directly into Excel. PowerPivot allows to store hundreds of millions of records in Excel file without making it slow. (works in Excel 2010 or later).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to install any add-ins. I will suggest it for future, but it would take weeks to raise a ticket and have it sorted. My options at this stage are either go through and do them all one by one, by hand, or try and get this macro to work! Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = rowcount To 1 Step -1 
    k = 0 
      For j = 1 To NumCol 
        If MyR.Value2(i, j) <> ""  and Rows(I, j).Hidden = false Then
```

I'm on my phone, so I can't test.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the help but unfortunately that one just throws up an error.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped...    How about ` If MyR.Value2(i,j) <> ""  and Rows(i).Hidden = false Then `

Comment: Hello,That was interesting on the test data. It worked on the unhidden rows as normal, but additionally deleted ALL the duplicates (including the first one) from the hidden rows, leaving no trace! Can't parse the code to figure out why, but either way, it's still bringing those hidden rows into the equation.

Comment: I'm going to try again when I get home from work.  I think the only way to do it is to loop through each row, or maybe use select>go to special>visible only, then advance filter and copy unique values to a new sheet.

Comment: When I typed "loop through each row", I meant loop through to find duplicates, without using RemoveDuplicates.   That surely will take a long time though

Comment: I've wracked my brain on this.   Other than looping through each row, checking to see if the row is hidden, then comparing to see if it is a duplicate, I can't figure out how to do this in vba.

Comment: I've wracked my brain on this.   Other than looping through each row, checking to see if the row is hidden, then comparing to see if it is a duplicate, I can't figure out how to do this in vba.     I think a quick way might be to filter your data,  then - Find Select ^  Goto special ^ Select Current Region ^ goto Special ^ select visible cells only^ copy and paste to new location ^ then goto Data ^ Data Tools ^ Remove Duplicates